# How would I embed an image in a PowerPoint 2016 table cell?

Tags: powerpoint

I would like to create a 7 column by 5 row table of JPG images a PowerPoint slide.

If I create a table in PowerPoint and insert an object from a JPG file, the image floats over the table.

Is there a way to put an image into a table cell in PowerPoint 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is in the same aspect ratio as the cell you mean to fill, or if you don't mind the image getting distorted if the aspect ratios don't match, fill the cell with the picture.

```
Sub TestIt()

    Dim oTbl As Table
    Set oTbl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(3).Table
    Call FillCellWithPicture(oTbl, 4, 2, "c:\temp\picture.jpg")

End Sub

Sub FillCellWithPicture(oTable As Table, lCol As Long, lRow As Long, sPicture As String)
    oTable.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.Fill.UserPicture (sPicture)
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting that there is no way to insert a picture in a table cell using commands on the ribbon.

Comment: It's there, it's just not all that intuitively obvious. You can right-click on a table cell and choose Format Shape from the pop-up menu or click in the cel and use the same Home tab | Drawing group | Shape Fill command you'd ordinarily use for shapes on the ribbon. We're in StackOverflow, so I originally answered from a "how to do this in code" POV.

Comment: Yes, Powerpoint is THAT weird. It has spectacular resources on one side, and lacks some functionalities for more than 10 years, go figure. But, it's worth to mention that although using the picture fill method DOES work, it's still limited. You either choose a distorted picture (because very rarely your image has the exact aspect ratio as the cell), or a tiling pattern. You have some margins to play with, where you can isolate only one copy of the image, centered - but in this case, say goodbye if you had a color background for the cell, or if the cell is part of an alternating color row.

Comment: I have the same problem. As @Charles Roberto Canato mentions, the fill method does not respect the ratio of the image. So, is there a solution ? Or are we still in the prehistory where such a basic thing is not possible with powerpoint ?

Comment: Is it possible to do this in some other program?  If so, try creating the table there, then copy/paste into PowerPoint.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian, inside Powerpoint, there is not. I ended up giving up on it and using a table screenshot. Yes, some part of me died by doing that, but I just moved on. :-)

Comment: @Charles Roberto Canatook : ok thank you. I will do the trick of "floating" the figures. But this is really a pity that these microsoft guys didn't think to this obvious needed functionality.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian What's obvious to the person who needs a functionality and finds it missing isn't necessarily obvious to the user base as a whole. I've been supporting PPT users/writing about PPT since the early 90's and this is the first time I've read of anyone wanting this (now that you mention it, YES, OBVIOUSLY useful) feature.  BTW, you *can* add pictures to tables in Word, so that's another workaround.

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg : thank you : you trick of word, that I didn't know, if extremely useful. This is very strange that microsoft guys implemented the functionality in word, but not in powerpoint, since somehow, this should share a common code.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian Totally agree!

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative method that will preserve the image aspect ratio, but the size is controlled by text size and not cell height/width, you cannot fill the entire height of cell either.

This is best for icons or status symbols but works for all images.

1. Select the cell
2. Expand the Bullet-list menu
3. Select Bullets and Numberings
4. Select the option Picture
5. Select a Picture, from your file system or through some of the other options
6. You get a preview of your Picture-bullet
7. Type a space as the bullet will not show if there is no text

Optional

8. Select the text, the space, and change font size to resize your image
9. Set vertical and horizontal alignment for the cell to have your picture display as you want
10. In the Bullets and Numberings menu you can increase the image size relative text size but you will get an offset.

PS. you can quickly hide the image by deleting the space, and then show it again by adding the space

I hope this can come to use...